# Запятая перед как

Tags: как, пунктуация

Во время войны хлеба, как основного продукта, не хватало. Правильно ли расставлены запятые. Вроде бы хлеб выступает в качестве основного продукта, а может, оборот с как выступает как пояснение?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

> *Во время войны хлеба, как основного продукта, не хватало. Правильно ли
> расставлены запятые.*

Запятые-то расставлены правильно, да... А нужно ли это пояснение: "как основного продукта"?

Может, лучше обойтись без него: *"Во время войны хлеба не хватало" ?*

Ну или заменить "как основного продукта" причастным оборотом:

*"Во время войны хлеба, являвшегося основным продуктом питания [населения] , не хватало".*

Answer (score 0):

Оборот с "как" выступает явно в значении "в качестве", поэтому запятые не нужны. Кроме того, у Розенталя есть и такое примечание: "Не обособляется также приложение с союзом "как", характеризующее предмет с какой-либо одной стороны: Читающая публика успела привыкнуть к Чехову как юмористу"

Comment: спасибо, я согласна.

Comment: виктор1799: "запятые не нужны."===

А если бы оборот был на одно-два  слова длиннее, тоже были бы не нужны?

"Во время войны хлеба как основного продукта питания населения не хватало." (?)===

По-моему, здесь само слово "как" -- лишнее.

Comment: Запятые нужны, поскольку "не хватало хлеба" в любом его качестве (нет качества, в котором его бы тогда "хватало"). Вставленное поясняет, насколько это плохо: заменить его чем-то другим нельзя. Здесь менее важны формальные признаки (использование "как"; возможно, это и стилистический недостаток).